# Write a program which performs brute force letter combination until the word "password" is found

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The program should print every letter combination (lowercase or uppercase, it doesn't matter) in alphabetic order. It must start with `a` and the last printed combination should be `password`.

The output should be:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab ac ... passwora passworb passworc password
```

Comment: Do the separators have to be spaces, or can I use newlines?

Comment: Yes you can, it is just a minor change.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Perl, 19 chars

```
say for a..password
```

Uses newlines as delimiters, per clarification above.  Run with `perl -M5.010` (or just `perl -E 'say for a..password'`) to enable the Perl 5.10+ `say` feature.  Per [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), this doesn't count as extra chars.

(If you insist on spaces as delimiters, `$,=$";say a..password` is only two chars longer.  However, it's also *very* slow and wasteful of memory, to the point of being unusable in practice, since it tries to build the entire list in memory before printing it.)

Answer (score 18):

### Ruby, 33 chars (optimal but longer version)

```
?a.upto('password'){|c|$><<c+' '}
```

I like the `'a'.upto('password')`; it tells you *exactly* what it's doing. Ruby is great and expressive like that. `:D`

Of course, `print c,' '` would also be much clearer, but using `$>` is two characters shorter.

### Ruby, <s>29</s> 25 chars (slow version)

```
$><<[*?a..'password']*' '
```

This one's shorter, but it prints all of the tokens at once, so it takes a long, long time to run!

Comment: Nice, especially the first.

Comment: In the slow version, `(?a..'password').to_a` can be shortened to `[*?a..'password']`

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 24 characters

A solution in 32 characters:

```
$_=a;print$_++,$"until/passwore/
```

Not much to say about this one. I could reduce this to 27 characters if I could use newlines instead of spaces to separate the entries.

[Ilmari Karonen points out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12619/4201) that `..` internally calls `++`, so a better solution (25 characters) would be:

```
print$_,$"for a..password
```

By taking advantage of Perl's command-line options, here's an equivalent 24-character solution:

```
perl -l40e 'print for a..password'
```

[The rules for counting perl flags](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions/274#274) is here, for those who aren't familiar with them.

Of course, [Ilmari's 21-character solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12619/4201) is shorter still, but it requires a machine that can allocate an array of 129,052,722,140 strings.

Comment: Wouldn't `.$"` instead of `," "` save a character?

Comment: Yep, total oversight on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl 6, 20 chars

```
say "a".../password/
```

You don't need other things

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 91

```
b=lambda n:n*' 'and b(n/26-(n%26<1))+chr(~-n%26+97)
i=0
exec"i+=1;print b(i);"*129052722140
```

Answer (score 4):

### PHP <del>38</del> <del>37</del> 36 characters

```
<?for($w=a;$w<passwore;)echo$w++,~ß;
```

You have to set the encoding to ISO 8859-1 and disable warnings.

Comment: I didn't test that, but does it really do that???

Comment: @ST3 It's a simple loop. The variable `$w` is initially set to 'a' and then is incremented until it reaches the first value after 'password' (the last string is not printed).

Comment: It looks suspicious for me, did you made a test? (I know it would be very long, so just to make from a to aa and from passwoqz to password). So is it tested or you think it should do the work?

Comment: @ST3 It is a regular `for` loop. There is nothing strange in this code, except for the last 2 characters, which are a bitwise-inverted whitespace. Anyway, yes, I tested it up to a shorter word.

Comment: I just checked that, it does nothing.

Comment: @ST3 Here is [a test](http://codepad.org/Jdu8oXcv) from `passwoqs` to `password`. Because the encoding of codepad is not ISO 8859-1, I had to replace `~ß` with a whitespace.

Comment: @ST3 And [this one](http://codepad.org/yRIfvnft) is from `a` to `az`.

Comment: I have to admit, it works. However I tested it in my own computer and it did nothing, probably it depends on php version and settings. So now agree that your answer is correct.

Comment: @ST3 Maybe you have `short_open_tag` set to false in your configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure, because I'm not a php developer, so know only basics about it...

Comment: You can save a char with `$w<passwore` in stead of `$w!=passwore`.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Thanks I changed it!

Comment: It doesn't work with < passwore. In a test from a to ba it stops a b, with != it works again.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby (40 characters)

Interpret a string of a-z letters as a number in base 26, with a = 1, b = 2,
..., z = 26.

So "password" can be thought of as the number N =

```
16*(26**7) + 
1*(26**6) + 
19*(26**5) + 
19*(26**4) + 
23*(26**3) + 
15*(26**2) + 
18*(26**1) + 
4*(26**0)
```

If we let `s = "a"` (that is: 1) and we make (N-1) calls to `s.succ!`, s will be `"password"` (N). In other words, N = 1 + (N-1).

For an example that will run more quickly, to prove the calculation of N is correct, consider `"pass"` as the target, where N is

```
16*(26**3) + 
1*(26**2) + 
19*(26**1) + 
19*(26**0)
```

and

```
s = "a"
(N-1).times { s.succ! }
puts s #== "pass"
```

Since we want to print `"a"` too, we need

```
s = "`"
N.times { print(s.succ! + " ") }
```

So back to the full "password". `N = 129052722140`, leaving:

```
s=?`;0x1e0c2443dc.times{$><<s.succ!+" "}
```

I hunted for a more compact form of `129052722140 == 0x1e0c2443db` but couldn't find one.

(Updated to fix the lack of printing `"a"`, thanks to Cary.)

Comment: Adam, that must have been you in my mind-meld.  Don't you want s to start one before 'a'?

Comment: I think what you're getting at is that I've used `N` instead of `N-1` in my iterations! Thanks, I'll edit to fix. (Although 129052722140 is an [interesting number to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=129052722140) :).)

Comment: 0x1e0c2443db is just as many chars as 129052722139.

Comment: What I meant was that if `s=?a`, `s.succ!` starts at 'b'`.

Comment: Does anything other than the value of `N` change if you start one before `"a"`? I don't think this would lead to a shorter version.

Comment: With `s=?a` and `N-1` you get 'b c...password'; with `s =`<backtick> and `N` you get 'a b...password'.  The SO requested the output to begin with `'a'`. That's all.

Comment: D'oh. I'm an idiot. Edited yet again to fix.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript, 73**

Here is a 73 character version of @Briguys' code, which prints only letter combinations

`for(i=s=0;1982613533018>i++;s=i.toString(36))/\d/.test(s)||console.log(s)`

Answer (score 2):

### APL(Dyalog), <s>46</s> 34

```
{∇{'PASSWORD '≡⍞←⍵:→⋄⍵}¨⎕A∘.,⍵}' '
```

Theoretically, it would print until PASSWORD, but I encountered a work space full error after ZZZZ: 5-dimensional array is just too awesome.

EDIT: Must have been too long since I last fiddled with APL. How dare I missed the identity comparision (`≡`)!!!

#### Explanation

`{...}`: Declares a function which...
`⎕A∘.,⍵`: Takes the outer product over concatenation (Every combination of an element of the left operand concatenated with an element of the right operand, just like Cartesian Product) between the 26 uppercase alpha (`⎕A`) and the argument (`⍵`)

`{...}¨`: And for each element of the resulting set, plug that into a function which...
`⍞←⍵`: prints it out
`'PASSWORD '≡` and compare it with `'PASSWORD '`
`→`: If the comparison returns true (`1`), then abort the program.
`⍵`: Else just return the printed string.

`∇`: Finally, the outer function recurse itself.

(Then you are taking outer product over concat between the 26 alpha and the 26 alpha, which gives all the 2-letter combinations, and then outer product over concat between the 2-letter combinations and the 26 alpha, etc... Until you reach PASSWORD which triggers the abort)

`' '`: The spark!! That kick-start the recursive function with the space character.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - <s>153 152 151</s> 149 bytes

```
from itertools import*;R=range
for l in iter(chain(*[product(*((map(chr,R(65,91)),)*n))for n in R(1,9)]).next,tuple("passwore")):print ''.join(l)
```

Saved one byte by using UPPERCASE and one by using newlines instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

#### Golfscript 41

For lack of `'z'+1 == 'aa'` logic Golfscript can't win this one.

```
168036262484,(;{27base{96+}%' '+.96?0<*}%
```

- `168036262484,` create array from 0 to 168036262483
- `(;` drop the 0
- `{` .. `}%` iterate over array
- `27base` convert element to base 27 array
- `{96+}%` add 96 to each digit
- `' '+` convert to string and add a space to the end
- `.96?0<*` truncate string to zero if it contains char 96

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, <s>39</s> 40.

```
a=&`
0x1e0c2443dc.times{$><<a.succ!+' '}
```

..or `129052722140`.  (Edit: formerly I had `129052722`.  I had lost some digits cutting and pasting.  Previous hex (`0x7B13032`) was for incorrect number.). Borrowed `` a=?` `` from @Doorknob to saves a character.

Comment: I tried to fix the ``a=?` `` thing, it looks kinda weird and has an extra space at the end but at least it works :P

Comment: So where does the number 129052722 come from? By my calculation, that would seem to give you the range "a" to "kwkokg" ... a bit small.

Comment: @Breadbox I calculated that number with the following method (sorry for the formatting, but comments have limitations, eh?): `ORD_BASE_ASCII = 'a'.ord-1;
def nbr(word);
  len = word.size;
  word.split('').inject(0) {|t,c|
    offset = c.ord - ORD_BASE_ASCII;
     t + offset*(26**(len -= 1))};
end
`It's easy to confirm this is correct by just printing out some sequences.

Comment: @breadbox You were right. See edit. Method I gave in comment is OK.

Comment: Fencepost errors. Your script is calculating using a=1..z=26. You need to calculate a=0..z=25 to get the right count. Removing the -1 from the first line, you'll get 120699639557, which (adding one for the zeroth entry) matches my calculation.

Comment: @breadbox Try this with the method nbr() in my earlier comment:
`def pr(word); a = '<backtick>'; n = nbr(word); puts "n = #{n}"; n.times{$><<a.succ!+' '}; end`
For example, `pr('diva') => a b ...  diuz diva`.  (diva? My dog.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm completely wrong. z winds up playing the role of the zero value. (Because a != aa != aaa, etc.) Ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript:  <del>57</del> 56 characters (thanks C5H8NNaO4)

Here's a solution that includes numbers as possible characters ("0", "1", "2", .., "passwor9", "passwora", "passworb", "passworc", "password")

```
for(i=-1;i++<1982613533017;console.log(i.toString(36)));
```

[Here's a fiddle for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/yCqW7/) (with only the last 100 iterations so it doesn't lock up your browser).

Comment: This solution is wrong, it doesn't follow the specification.

Comment: @Doorknob - Yes, I mentioned that in my answer.  It still prints all cases from the original requirements, but prints all alpha-numeric cases as well.

Comment: Also, after re-reading the question, if I set i to 9 in my code, it would meet ALL the question's requirements except for his example output, which he has already given an exception for (and it would bring the code to 56 characters).

Comment: @Briguy37 The spec says `print every **letter** combination`
Anyway, save a character: `{} -> ;`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4:  Which letter combination does my solution not print?  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Briguy37 It's not printing only letter only combination, I don't think it goes with the spec even if you don't print the first 9 numbers. You're welcome :)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4:  I know it is nit-picky and I feel like a weasel, but the specs say "print every letter combination", not "print only letter combinations", so I disagree.

Comment: @Briguy I would not see a number as letter but well, it can't be made clear until the spec would be updated. If you want you can put my answer into yours, as addition for completeness' sake, I would then delete mine and +1 yours'

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 101

```
main=putStrLn.concat.takeWhile(/="passwore ").tail.concat.iterate(\k->[x:y|x<-['a'..'z'],y<-k])$[" "]
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript <s>80</s> 76

```
for(i=s=0;s!="password";i++){s=i.toString(36).replace(/[0-9]/,'');console.log(s)}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/9Jnpf/) - stops at "pa".

however this does repeat things.

Comment: You can initialize the loop with `i=s=0` to save three more characters.

Comment: @minitech done.

Comment: Why keep the `var`? `i` was a global before; now `s` is a global. You can just keep both globals in code golf, usually.

Answer (score 0):

### Befunge (72)

```
<_v#:/*2+67\+++88*99%*2+76:
^ >$>:#,_84*+,1+:0\:" Lr$W~"67++**1+***6+`#@_
```

Prints strings 'a' to 'password' separated by spaces, then exits.

Below is a version that prints only the first 9*9 = 81 words ('a' to 'dd'), for comparison.  The `99*` is the number of iterations to perform.

```
<_v#:/*2+67\+++88*99%*2+76:
^ >$>:#,_84*+,1+:0\:99*`#@_
```